# Azure Web Deploy Suddenly Failing

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, webdeploy

I have a web application in a test environment set up in Azure to which I regularly publish updates from Visual Studio (2017) using Web Deploy. The publish profile was created by importing the publish profile downloaded from the Azure App Service that hosts the website.

Suddenly I've started getting a publish error. The following is how the error is reported in the Output window:

```
bin\Any CPU\Release\net452\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation-x86.exe @"obj\Any CPU\Release\net452\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"
'bin\Any' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\marks\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\1.1.0\build\net451\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.targets(36,5): Error MSB3073: The command "bin\Any CPU\Release\net452\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation-x86.exe @"obj\Any CPU\Release\net452\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp"" exited with code 9009.

2>Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This publish process has worked fine previously, but has suddenly stopped working. I have tried deleting the Visual Studio publish profile, regenerating it in Azure, re-download it and import into Visual Studio, but the problem persists. There was a very recent update to Visual Studio, which I installed, so it may have something to do with that.

I've noticed that under the bin folder I now have three sub-folders: "Debug", "Release", and "Any CPU". I have never noticed the "Any CPU" folder previously, though I don't recall explicitly looking in the bin folder, so maybe it's always been there. Both the Debug and Release builds are configured for "Any CPU".

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had similar after upgrading my VS2017 and am trying to remember how I sorted it out. Backup your code, then:  1) Do a full clean of the solution (Build->Clean solution). Close the solution.
2) Clean your temp files, go to Start->Run->%Temp% and remove the files in the folder. 3) Open the solution and reinstall your nuget packages. (Update-Package -reinstall). 5) Then rebuild and redeploy. You may also try updating your project / solution to .net 4.6.1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Murray. Unfortunately, it doesn't seemed to have helped in my case - I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: HAve you tried from another VM / machine?

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but to help anyone get out of a jam if they hit this error -

Turning off Razor compile in your `csproj` file will at least get you publishing again until a true fix is found/suggested.

`<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>`